# firewalld rich-rule equivalent in ufw

Tags: linux, firewall, ipsec, ufw

For controlling `iptables`, I stopped using `firewalld` and I use `ufw` instead.

I need to apply these rules, but using `ufw`:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="esp" accept' # ESP (the encrypted data packets)
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="ah" accept' # AH (authenticated headers)
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-port=500/udp #IKE  (security associations)
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-port=4500/udp # IKE NAT Traversal (IPsec between natted devices)
```

I know the last two are easy as `ufw allow 500/udp, ufw allow 4500/udp`

How can I translate the first two rich-rules, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like

```
ufw allow proto esp from any
ufw allow proto ah from any
```

And corresponding to rules

```
ufw allow proto esp to any
ufw allow proto ah to any
```